# Ring theory(addition table)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

(S,+,.) is a ring , where S={a,b,c,d}. Complete the table.
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
+ & a & b & c & d \\ 
\hline
a &a  &b  &c  &d \\ 
b &b  &1 &2  &3\\ 
c &c  &4   &5  &a\\ 
d &d &6  &7  &8
\end{array}
$$
The missing cells can be numbered as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 from left to right.
$$
1=2b\\
2=b+c\\
3=b+d\\
4=b+c\\
5=2c\\
6=d+b\\
7=d+c\\
8=2d\\
$$
From the table the identity is a and since $c+d=a$ ,$d=c$ inverse and $c= d$ inverse.

I think all the answers should be a single letter but I can't simplify any further with the information given. Any type of help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Is it an addition table (per the question text) or a multiplication table (per the title)?

Comment: $S$ is an additive group; in the addition table for a finite group, every row and column must contain every element of the group exactly once.

Comment: It is an addition table

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

> In a ring, the addition table is the table of a group. What are the groups of order $4$?

*Partial solution:*

> There are two groups of order $4$: $C_4$ and $C_2 \times C_2$

*Full solution:*

> There are two rings of size $4$: $\mathbb Z_4$ and $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$

Comment: I know that their are cyclic groups of order 4. But that does not imply that this group is cyclic.